# How to configure SonarQube for Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sonarqube

I want configure SonarQube with Xcode project for only Objective-C. I am not able to find working JAR for Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

[SonarSource](https://www.sonarsource.com/) provides [SonarCFamily for Objective-C](https://www.sonarsource.com/products/codeanalyzers/sonarcfamilyforobjectivec.html) is a plugin. It is available in [Developer](https://www.sonarsource.com/plans-and-pricing/developer/) and [Enterprise](https://www.sonarsource.com/plans-and-pricing/enterprise/) editions.

There is also a free alternative on GitHub: https://github.com/Backelite/sonar-objective-c. The latest version (0.6.2) is compatible with SonarQube 6.7.